# JIRA as a Test Case Management Tool

Tags: jira, testcase

So our Company just started using Jira, and i've created a new "Issue" type for Test Plans.

However I'm sorta running into the problem of that when creating a "session" in Jira (Capture for instance) that test plans and actual bugs are all kinda under the same thing.

It seems to me that Jira was never meant to really be used to store test plans, am I missing something? I've looked at the Jira guides to make it work for keeping test plans, but it just seems so convoluted and overly complex that it seems like another TCM tool makes more sense.

Has anyone else ran into this? Am I missing a better way to do TCM with Jira?

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JIRA is a ticketing system.

As it's marketing buzzword bingo says: "Issue tracking and code integration to plan, collaborate, and ship great products." It does more if you find or create the necessary plugins.

It does issue tracking by itself, and code integration with other Atlassian platforms.

It does *not* do test management.
There are plugins for that (like Zephyr) by third parties, but in general, I don't recommend mixing test case management with issue tracking. Make your separate TCM tool to create a ticket in your separate ticketing system.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I figured. I tried out Zephyr...but it felt clumsy and didn't really change my original problem of all the "issues" getting lumped together, also requires 2 steps to actually "add" individual steps to each test plan. Needless to say I wasn't a fan.

Comment: If you find an useful one, please let me know :-)

Comment: I think were going to end up using TestRail, it seems simple enough for what we need.